Pricing of Exotic FX options: One touch down/No touch up and One touch up/No touch down
Does anybody know of a book or paper where the pricing model of One touch down/No touch up and One touch up/No touch down fx options is described? The conditions for this options are:
With:
St = Spot value at time t;
Bl = Lower barrier;
Bh = Upper barrier
One touch down/No touch up:  $\exists t\le$Expiry $\ (S_{\rm t}\le\ B_{\rm l, }$$\forall$u$\le t \  S_{\rm u}\le\ B_{\rm h})$
One touch up/No touch down:  $\exists t\ge$Expiry $\ (S_{\rm t}\ge\ B_{\rm h, }$$\forall$u$\le t\ S_{\rm u}\ge\ B_{\rm l})$
Thanks
